# Java, regex to split a string on a delimiter with constraints

Tags: java, regex, base64

I have a malformed base64 string in java.

It's not absolutely malformed but the string sometimes contains more base64 encoded data.

I want to split the string, and I think regex is the best way to achieve this.

There are cases:

- if there is only one base64 in the string, it either

  - does not contain any padding char `=`
  - contains padding char(s) (one or two) **only** at the end
- if there are more base64 in the string, it will

  - contain padding char(s) (one or two) **not at the end** (or not only at the end)

Now I want to get a `String[]` which holds the single base64 strings.

So regex does not have to split if there is no padding char, or the padding char is at the end.
But it has to split if there is padding char in the middle (and there can be one ore two padding chars).

Test snippet:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;

/*
TEST CASES:
output array shall contain one item only
TG9y
TG9yZW0=
TG9yZQ==

output array shall contain two items
TG9yZW0=TG9y
TG9yZW0=TG9yZW0=
TG9yZW0=TG9yZQ==

TG9yZQ==TG9y
TG9yZQ==TG9yZW0=
TG9yZQ==TG9yZQ==

output array shall contain three items
TG9yZW0=TG9yZW0=TG9y
TG9yZQ==TG9yZW0=TG9y
...
*/

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    String buffer = "";

    try {
      byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(buffer.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      System.out.println(new String(decodedString));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.err.println("Buffer: " + buffer);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if regex is fully capable of this, or if it is the best method to do this.

Comment: What if the first item is `TG9y`? How do you know where it ends?

Comment: show your regex code and input & expected output

Comment: To split after 1 or more `=` signs, use a combination of *zero-width positive lookbehind* and *zero-width negative lookahead*: `String[] arr = buffer.split("(?<==)(?!=)")`

Comment: @Andreas: What if the first item is `TG9y`? In that case it does not need to be split. Base64 parser decodes concatenated base64s if they don't have the padding character in between.

Comment: So if the original input was `{ "Lor", "Lore", "Lorem" }`, resulting in combined Base64 text `TG9yTG9yZQ==TG9yZW0=`, you're ok with that decoding back to `{ "LorLore", "Lorem" }`, losing the separation of the first two inputs?

Comment: @Andreas yes, totally good, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61009784/java-regex-to-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-with-constraints/61011583#comment107936578_61009784), you can split the string after an `=` *equal* sign, that isn't followed by an `=` *equal* sign, by using a combination of `(?<=X)` *zero-width positive lookbehind* and `(?!X)` *zero-width negative lookahead*:

```
String[] arr = input.split("(?<==)(?!=)");
```

*Test*

```
String[] inputs = {
        "TG9y",
        "TG9yZW0=",
        "TG9yZQ==",
        "TG9yZW0=TG9y",
        "TG9yZW0=TG9yZW0=",
        "TG9yZW0=TG9yZQ==",
        "TG9yZQ==TG9y",
        "TG9yZQ==TG9yZW0=",
        "TG9yZQ==TG9yZQ==",
        "TG9yZW0=TG9yZW0=TG9y",
        "TG9yZQ==TG9yZW0=TG9y",
        "TG9yTG9yZQ==TG9yZW0=" };
Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
for (String input : inputs) {
    String[] arr = input.split("(?<==)(?!=)");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = new String(decoder.decode(arr[i]), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

*Output*

```
[Lor]
[Lorem]
[Lore]
[Lorem, Lor]
[Lorem, Lorem]
[Lorem, Lore]
[Lore, Lor]
[Lore, Lorem]
[Lore, Lore]
[Lorem, Lorem, Lor]
[Lore, Lorem, Lor]
[LorLore, Lorem]
```